# What are the criteria used to determine which Tagged Questions get pushed as RSS feeds?

Tags: discussion, feed

Any of the following leads to having a new entry in an RSS feed reader:

- New Questions
- Edited Questions
- Edited Answers

But sometimes I see some posts that don't fulfill above criteria in my Google Reader client. I'd guess they were posts bumped by Community User, but that's not the case with [this post](https://askubuntu.com/q/1943/2591) (which got fed to my reader 2011.02.10).

Comment: One more example: [Old post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983862/sql-server-operator) on the sql-server tag